# dynamic created images in canvas to h264

Tags: image, video, canvas, stream

I'm trying to built in an application that transforms the several canvas objects dynamically and constantly created into an h264 video stream.

I'm working with node.js now but i can change.

Can you please suggest me the best way to to this?

Thanks in advance.

Eduardo

Comment: How often do you need to h264 encode your animated canvas?  If just a few times, use SnagIt to capture the canvas--it generates h264.  I googled a bit and couldn't find h264 encoders.  That may be because commercial use of h264 requires distributors to pay per-user royalties on that codec.  Just a thought---You might have more luck finding webm or ogg encoders.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. To answer your first question: Very often. I've thought to use something connected to wowza producing the video, i tried many solutions but no luck. Thanks

Comment: Are you hoping to programatically capture the the graphical contents of the canvas via JavaScript and, ideally, encode video via JavaScript or some other in-browser technology?

Comment: The idea is to create the canvas element at server side and the stream as a h264 video stream. Thanks